# How do I remove the 00:00:00 from my string

Tags: python, string, pandas, date

I am trying to delete the 00:00:00(HH:MM:SS) from my link using pandas.

```
https://www.z-ratos.com/orical/?from=USD&amount=0&date=2018-10-24 00:00:00
```

So How I delete this 00:00:00 from my link so that its working properly.
I tried this code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import *

# TO TAKE DATE DIFFERENCE IN LIST
today = datetime.today()
dates = pd.date_range('2018-10-13', today)
#print(dates)

for i in dates:
    #print(i)
    url = 'https://www.z-ratos.com/orical/?from=USD&amount=0&date%s'%i
    print(url)
```

Comming output is:

```
https://www.z-ratos.com/orical/?from=USD&amount=0&date=2018-10-24 00:00:00
    .....
     ......
      ......
```

Required Output is:

```
https://www.z-ratos.com/orical/?from=USD&amount=0&date=2018-10-24
```

So please help
thanks in Advance...

Comment: What about using `string.split()`?

Answer (score 6):

Use `strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`

**Ex:**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import *

# TO TAKE DATE DIFFERENCE IN LIST
today = datetime.today()
dates = pd.date_range('2018-10-13', today)
#print(dates)

for i in dates:
    #print(i)
    url = 'https://www.z-ratos.com/orical/?from=USD&amount=0&date%s'%i.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    print(url)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) for strings:

```
dates = pd.date_range('2018-10-13', today).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

And then `format` or [`f-strings`](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/):

```
for i in dates:
    #print(i)
    url = 'https://www.z-ratos.com/orical/?from=USD&amount=0&date={}'.format(i)
    #python 3.6+ solution
    #url = f'https://www.z-ratos.com/orical/?from=USD&amount=0&date={i}'
    print(url)
```

Comment: @royal - yes, sure, in my opinion much better is use `format` or `f-string`s like `%s`, check [this link](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

Comment: Thanks, but one answer is enough.  Do me a favor and add the bit about using the formatting codes within the f-string.  Or within the `str.format` as well.  `'{:%Y-%m-%d}'.format(i)` should work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `date` method of a `Datetime` object. To remove the timestamp from all your dates:

```
dates = [d.date() for d in dates]
```

Alternatively just use `i.date()` when you iterate through the dates.